# How to refresh UIWebView when app comes to foreground?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to refresh a UIWebView whenever my app comes to the foreground.  All I really have in my ViewController.m is a method that checks for internet access (hasInternet) and viewDidLoad.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webview;

-(BOOL)hasInternet{
    Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.google.com"];
    NetworkStatus internetStats = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (internetStats == NotReachable) {
        UIAlertView *alertOne = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You're not connected to the internet." message:@"Please connect to the internet and restart the app." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertOne show];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self hasInternet];
    [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://warm-chamber-7399.herokuapp.com/"]] ];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Any advice on how to enable this functionality?  Does it go in AppDelegate or do I create another method within ViewController.m?

Comment: Only use the [tag:Xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You should register a `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method and whenever app comes back from background you can do whatever you want to do in the method registered for notification. `ViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` won't be called when app comes back from background to foreground.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doYourStuff)

    name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)doYourStuff{

  [webview reload];
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the notification you are registered for.

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

**Note** if you register your `viewController` for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` then your method would be called everytime your app becomes active, It would not be appropriate to register for this notification.

Answer (score 0):

Register for the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification or the UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification.

Comment: how do I register for this?  I'm new to ios and xcode.  IS there a tutorial you'd recommend?

Comment: It is a notification (NSNotification), listed in the UIApplication class documentation.

Comment: If you don't know what a notification is, you could read the section of my book that explains it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_notifications